# How does text on SVG not update but text on a div does?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have two different ways of writing text :

selecting the `div` with `id 'view'`

```
1 - d3.select("#view").text("your title is:" + title)
```

and appending text to the `svgContainer`

```
2 - d3.select("#svgContainer").append("g").append("text")text("your title is:" + title);
```

I have different layouts on the right hand side which when clicked the text gets updated. If I use the first way, the old title gets removed and the new title is shown. But when I use the second way the old title stays there and the new title just gets added on to the end and I am unsure why.

Why do these to ways of writing text behave differently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name says it: `.append()` appends a new `g` node to the container. You rather want to select the existing text node inside the container:

```
d3.select('#svgContainer text').text('mynewtext');
```